# workout information send to phone live

Tags: iphone, swift, apple-watch, heartbeat

I have created a heart rate monitor on the apple watch and that sends alerts to notifies you if your heart rate gets to low. After creating the app, I realized it does not run in the background. Is there a way to either force the app to run in the background on the watch or send the heart rate information to the phone?

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated this, but don't have any practical experience (yet). 
From what I understand, watch apps in watchOS3 can capture continuous heart rate updates with these conditions:

- It's a full app (not just an extension).
- The app starts a workout
- Info.plist has the `WKBackgroundModes` key set

You'll need to either start the workout from the watch app, or if triggered from the companion iOS app you'll need to call `start​Watch​App​With​Workout​Configuration:​completion:​` to start a workout session on the paired watch.

p.s. welcome to stackoverflow!